# add a sequence of numbers to a column in pandas data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I want to add a column with values 0, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015...up to the length of the df, how do I proceed? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only Pandas:

```py
df = df.assign(newcol=pd.Series(range(df.shape[0])) * 0.005)
```

Using Numpy:

```py
df = df.assign(newcol=np.arange(df.shape[0]) * 0.005)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get there would be with the `numpy.arange` function:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_column'] = np.arange(0, (df.shape[0]*0.005), 0.005)
```